# Android Greendao to auto increment always be long

Tags: android, database, greendao, greenrobot-eventbus

Android Greendao to auto increment always be long thats why its can't increment value automatically Please help us to how we can create schema to automatically get as Long

My code is here

```
        Entity label = schema.addEntity("SecureNotes");

        label.addIdProperty().primaryKey().autoincrement().notNull();
        label.addStringProperty("category_name").notNull();
        label.addStringProperty("title");
        label.addStringProperty("description");
        label.addIntProperty("color_code");
        label.addDateProperty("created_date").notNull();
        label.addDateProperty("updated_date");
        label.addBooleanProperty("is_master_password").notNull();
        label.implementsSerializable();
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer after removing notNull() its remove the issues and working as charm!!!!!